# Animation in Three.js JSON Files

Tags: three.js

I have a question on a problem I've been struggling with.

I have been trying to figure out if the "bones" member in the Three.js JSON file format is supposed to be the bind pose of a skeleton?

I ask because, at the moment, I am exporting an avatar from DAZ Studio to Three.js, and that works fine. But as soon as I add the bones and animation everything is distorted. Basically, stretched out in the X and Y plane. I assume this is because I am exporting the "bones" and the "animation" members incorrectly. (Currently, I export the bind pose to the "bones" member).

The issue is that when I look for documentation on what is supposed to go into those fields, I can't really find anything. (Currently I just copied the format of the buffalo.js sample file on the three.js site). But obviously, I am outputting the bone translations, rotations and scales in the wrong coordinate space. Or maybe they should all be the bind pose??? I'm not sure... because I can't find anything to reference. I tried to use the blender exporter as a guide, but blender spaces and armatures are significantly different from what you find in DAZ Studio or Unity 3D.

If there is anyone out there who is familiar with the required coordinate spaces for values in the "bones" and "animation" members of the Three.js JSON file format, I would appreciate any guidance you could give me.

I am a bit too perplexed at the moment, and thought this might be a good time to "reset" and ask for a bit of guidance.

Thanx in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: HI My friend I looking for the same solution to use the animation on playcanvas.copm which is a webgl based cloud framework, anyways, can you please point me in the right direction in how to export the Json file from Daz3D ??  I will try in my engine framework and I will tell you if its deforming my characters as well